# css:background-color for main menu sub1 and sub2 not displaying

Tags: css, menu, background-color, navigationbar

In my following navigation bar menu, all elements are getting displayed in blue. How can I get sub1 and sub2 to display in orange and list elements in blue?

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
ul{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
background-color:#33CCFF;/*orange is not displaying*/
}
li{float:left;
display:block;
width:120px;
text-align:center;
padding:4px;
color:#FFFFFF;
background-color:;#FFCC33;}/*blue*/
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="menu">
<li id="menu1">Sub 1
    <ul>
        <li>test 1</li>
        <li>test 2</li>
        <li>test 3</li>
        <li>test 4</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li id="menu2">Sub 2
    <ul>
        <li>test 1</li>
        <li>test 2</li>
        <li>test 3</li>
        <li>test 4</li>
    </ul>
</li>
      </ul>     
      </body>
```

Comment: Wnat like this http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/L7rBF/

Comment: it works fine after removing the padding.

Comment: instead of ul>li li{background-color:...}, i put ul>li>ul>li{background-color:.....}. AFter reading up further from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227322/css-selectors-ul-li-a-vs-ul-li-a, i found out that the second li will get all lis under the first li (ie. descendents). Using my method, it will get the child of the first li (ie. ul) and then it will get the child of ul (ie. li).

Comment: ya i know it selects only direct children. Here is a great article about all these selectors http://web-design-weekly.com/2012/05/31/css-selectors-that-rock/. I just tried to make its working as soon as possible. As you can see its the first comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul id="menu">
<li id="menu1"><span>Sub 1</span>
    <ul>
        <li>test 1</li>
        <li>test 2</li>
        <li>test 3</li>
        <li>test 4</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li id="menu2"><span>Sub 2</span>
    <ul>
        <li>test 1</li>
        <li>test 2</li>
        <li>test 3</li>
        <li>test 4</li>
    </ul>
</li>
      </ul>
```

**css**

```
li{float:left;
  display:block;
  width:120px;
  text-align:center;
  padding:4px;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  background-color:;#FFCC33;}/*blue*/
}
#menu1 span,#menu2 span
{
color:orange;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/HtMLY/

check it out may b that's the result u want hope it solve your problem

Comment: this was actually an interview question. There was no span in that.

Comment: check updated code again here

http://jsfiddle.net/HtMLY/1/

hope its solve your question

Answer (score -1):

Modify the CSS selectors.

Try with this ones:

```
ul li{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
background-color:#FFCC33;/*orange is not displaying*/
}
ul li ul li{float:left;
display:block;
width:120px;
text-align:center;
padding:4px;
color:#FFFFFF;
background-color:#33CCFF;}/*blue*/
```

Like this you will define exactly which CSS has to be applied to the tree level you want. Like you were applying the same style for all ul and for all li, independently of the level they are.

Comment: no, this doesn't work. It changes the entire layout of the navigation bar.